# Как добавить pkgconfig в CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, python, компиляция, sax

Хочу заменить часть скриптов на Python более быстрыми аналогами на C++. В первую очередь интересует SAX парсеры из [libxml++-3.0](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/)
В дистрибутиве есть папка `examples`. Скомпилировать все примеры сразу получилось командой `make check`. Теперь нужно открыть содержимое `examples/sax_parser` в какой-нибудь IDE и запускать оттуда. Как выяснилось, это можно сделать десятками способов и все они нетривиальные.
В README к библиотеке упомянута только команда

> $ pkg-config libxml++-3.0 --cflags --libs
>   -I/usr/local/include/libxml++-3.0 -I/usr/local/lib/libxml++-3.0/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -L/usr/local/lib -lxml++-3.0 -lxml2 -lglibmm-2.4 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lsigc-2.0

Как записать результат её выполнения во что-нибудь вроде `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно именно добавить вывод pkg-config в cmake проект:
У Cmake есть модуль PkgConfig, который запускает и парсит вывод одноименной утилиты

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_search_module(LIBXML REQUIRED libxml++-3.0)
```

Вторая строка запишет в переменные все нужные данные(каталоги с хидерами, каталоги с библиотеками, флаги, список библиотек для линковки и т.д.)
Теперь просто используй переменные для указания всего нужного:

```
include_directories(${LIBXML_INCLUDE_DIRS})
compile_options(app_name ${LIBXML_CFLAGS}
link_libraries(app_name ${LIBXML_LIBRARIES}
```

Писал по памяти, может где неправильно что, поищи документацию FindPkgConfig

Answer (score 1):

1. Не надо взамен python использовать C++. Если желаете более быстрый аналог -- используйте cython. Неопытный программист на Си гарантированно проигрывает при замере скорости исполнения кода.
2. Беретё python. Делаете что-то вроде os.pipe (или даже можно без него в духе examples.txt || examples.py), и после этого успешно читаете входной поток и пишите в выходной всё, что хотите.